# I found a problem when trying to use express body-parser with koa-body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, koa, body-parser

I am using an API gateway architecture, the gateway API is coded in express, and the microservice I'm calling is made using Koa.

I'm trying to send multiple files encoded in base64 to the backend, without the body-parser in the gateway I get a `Payload Too Large 413` error, so after adding it I get this error: `Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START_BOUNDARY`.
If I remove the koa-body I get the error `Payload Too Large 413` again.
I suspected that the error is probably from the use of body-parser with koa-body.
The request from the frontend is sent through axios POST, and the values are in a FormData.

This is the koa-body code in the microservice:

```
.use(
      koaBody({
        multipart: true,
        formidable: {
          maxFieldsSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024,
          maxFileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024
        }
      })
    )
```

EDIT: Maybe it's not clear from the question, but the files aren't sent as files but as Base64 Strings.
EDIT2: After some research I found that the problem can be even in the proxy of the gateway API, which I found had some problems handling multi-part forms(https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy/issues/127).

Answer (score 0):

From [the `body-parser` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

> *This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:*
>
> - [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme) and [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy#readme)
> - [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty#readme) and [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty#readme)
> - [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme)
> - [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

*(their emphasis)*

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified more, I am sending them as Strings the files specifically  base64 Strings, which doesn't count as multipart body probably, and I did use connect-busboy after having read the docs, and it always gave me the problem of Payload Too Large, even after changing its limits.